# Azure Devops Test Plan ID not found using API

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api, test-plan

I am attempting to locate the test point ID's associated with test cases in my test plan.  I can clearly see the test plan/test suite #'s in the UI, yet when I make the call to get the test points I receive an error that my test plan is not found.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://dev.azure.com/MyCompany/MyProject/_apis/testplan/Plans/42687/Suites/42776/TestPoint?api-version=5.1-preview.2");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic myauthorization");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I can create/delete test runs with the API so I know my auth is good.  Why am I unable to see the test plan?

Comment: Not quite sure about your question. According to the api you are sharing in the code, you have already provided the Test Plan ID, then you still got the error could not found the Test Plan ID? If the Test Plan ID is correct? Try to use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20%20plans/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 API to list the Test Plan ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the user interface not being clear (or simply user error).
When looking at the UI, the test plan name is clearly shown when clicking on the test plan - however the test suite # is shown next to it, which was causing me the problem.  It took reading the URL to understand that the display was not what I expected.

[image]